# Kotlin : Public get private set var

Tags: kotlin

What is the correct way to define a var in kotlin that has a public getter and private (only internally modifiable) setter?

Answer (score 422, accepted):

```
var setterVisibility: String = "abc" // Initializer required, not a nullable type
    private set // the setter is private and has the default implementation
```

See: [Properties Getter and Setter](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters)

Comment: Note that `private set` must be on a new line.

Comment: ...or on the same line, after a semicolon: `var abc: String = ""; private set`

Comment: I'm at a loss for what to do with a primary constructor field though.

Comment: @user3175580 You mean how to create a private setter on a primary constructor property?

Comment: @D3xter precisely

Comment: @user3175580 This is not possible. Use a local field inside the primary constructor and then assign the value to the property like "class Foo(_bar: String) { var bar: String = _bar }

Comment: @JasperBlues ...otherwise, you need to add semicolon before `private set`.

Comment: I like the swift style a little better - `private(set) var abc : String = ""`

Comment: @androidguy Here a discussion about possible future syntax to have "Private setter for var in primary constructor" https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/private-setter-for-var-in-primary-constructor/3640/13

Comment: Semicolon? In Kotlin? What blasphemy is this? /s

Comment: What about if you want to use an observable with a private setter? ie: so you can perform some reactive logic when the value is set?

Comment: So the variable is public if you need to read its value, but it is private when attempting to set its value, hence, you cannot directly sets its value from the outside. Okay...

Answer (score 28):

#### Public getter, private setter

You can easily accomplish this using the following approach:

```
var atmosphericPressure: Double = 760.0
    get() {
        return field
    }
    private set(value) { 
        field = value 
    }
```

Look at [this post](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/getters-setters) for details.

Comment: isn't it `get() = field` redundant?