# Inline setter or Not to create unused setter in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I noticed that Kotlin create **setter** for **var**, and set value via **setter** instead of set it directly. Can we make setter **inline**? or set value directly without create **private setter** method by default?

```
lateinit var name: String
    private set
```

Comment: may be duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428957/kotlin-public-get-private-set-var

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate value with `@JvmField` annotation to instruct kotlin compiler to not generate a getter/setter pair for it:

```
@JvmField
private var name: String = "Joshua"
```

Also, for vals, if you have a `private val`, compiler won't generate a getter for it and produce a bytecode which would have it as an ordinary field.