# Kotlin only getter pulblic, private setter

Tags: kotlin

I just started using Kotlin and found getters and setters very useful.

I am wondering if Kotlin provides only getters public.

It should not be `val` because it's value can be changed by it's class.

What I've done to achieve this is as follows.

```
private var _score: Int=0
val score: Int = _score
   get() = _score
```

Using this way, I have to declare two variables.

Is there any better way to only make getters public?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can define the accessor without defining its body:

```
var score: Int = 0
    private set
```

In this case the setter is private.

From [the docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters):

> If you need to change the visibility of an accessor or to annotate it,
>   but don't need to change the default implementation, you can define
>   the accessor without defining its body:
>
> ```
> var setterVisibility: String = "abc"
>     private set // the setter is private and has the default implementation
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax :

```
var setterVisibility: String = "abc" // Initializer required, not a nullable type
    private set // the setter is private and has the default implementation
```

Please refer to the official [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters)

Also it's a doublon with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428957/kotlin-public-get-private-set-var)